# upgrading from 15.10 to 16.04 apt not installed

Tags: apt, upgrade, 16.04, 15.10

When trying to upgrade using the terminal, my upgrade stops. This is the line showing in the terminal:

```
The required dependency 'apt(>=1.0.10.2 ubuntu2)' is not installed.
```

my problem is that I don't know the command to install this dependency. Using other commands, it says apt is up to date. Solutions?

Comment: Have you tried using `sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get upgrade`, and `sudo apt-get install -f`?

Comment: yes, i've used all those commands. first two said i was up to date but terminal didn't recognize th install -f command

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get -y install apt` ?

Comment: answer,again is apt is already the newest version

Comment: no matter the install apt command i've tried, it always says i'm up to date!

Comment: Have you done an `apt-get autoremove` and clean? Then I would try `apt-get install -f` again.

Comment: both commands yielded same response with no changes. i used sudo apt-get autoremove, do i need a separate command for clean?

Comment: Yes, but if autoremove didn't work clean probably wouldn't work as well. I'm still a little confused, does "'apt(>=1.0.10.2 ubuntu2)' is not installed" appear every time you use apt-get or just on an upgrade?

Comment: i don't use apt-get a lot, on a previous upgrade, "discover" appeared and most updates occur that way but i don't like it very much. however, i have only seen this message when i've tried the upgrade to 16.04.

Comment: Can you send either a snap shot, temp ssh username, or teamviewer info to aklassen80@yahoo.com so I can see whats going on?

Comment: i really appreciate the help and i will happily do that if you can tell me the command to use to get that information.

Comment: run `sudo apt-get upgrade` then just take a picture of the output and send it to my email

Comment: I have the same issue. This problem appears every time I try to do a release upgrade. Not when I do a simple update/upgrade.

Comment: Emm, try "sudo apt-get dist-upgrade" first?

Answer (score 19):

Had the same problem, solved by forcing the update of apt and cleaning the current installation as Andrew suggested:

```sh
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get -f install   # (not "install -f"!)
sudo apt-get -y install apt
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Comment: there is something else blocking my installation of apt. following the instructions listed, it still indicates that apt is up-to-date. however, when i get to do-release-upgrade, it cannot find apt, or at least the correct apt.

Comment: `-f install` and `install -f` make no difference.

Comment: But that install from 15.10 to 16.xx sth.

Comment: @marko You just need to repeat the step a few times.

Answer (score 13):

I had this error, for me I was missing the wily-updates line from my /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-updates main restricted universe multiverse
```

Comment: For ARM etc. the line should be `deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ wily-updates main restricted universe multiverse`

Comment: I'm thinking that it should be "deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/   trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse" (i.e., it turns on the extra repos).  Mixing versions (e.g., trusty and wily) never ends well.

Comment: After doing that, "apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade && do-release-upgrade" appears to work.  Note: you may need to comment out the /tmp line in /etc/fstab, to avoid running out of temporary space.

Comment: This is essential if you upgrading from old Ubuntu version, like 15.xx. Also keep in mind that they no longer provide http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu url for wily and other old releases. Use http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ instead.

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue too, this will update all your goodies as well as upgrade from 15 to 16.

Go to `Software and Updates` > `Updates`

### Tick On the Following

- Wily Security
- Wily Updates
- Wily Proposed

#### Update and Upgrade Current System

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

#### Get the Upgrade

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

#### Upgrade in CLI

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem with 'apt'. I got the solution from [this link](http://forum.ubuntu.org.cn/viewtopic.php?t=477731&p=3163329). Run `sudo dpkg -l | grep apt`. You may see this entry in the output of the command :

```
ii  apt 1.0.10.2ubuntu1      amd64         commandline package manager
```

If you do, you will need to get the required **apt(>=1.0.10.2 ubuntu2)**. Here are the steps which I followed :

1. Go to Software & Update -> Ubuntu Software . Change the Server to Main server.(in my case, I changed to Server for India). I was using a different mirror previously and hence had an older 'apt' version.
2. Run

   ```
       sudo apt-get update
       sudo apt-get install --reinstall apt
   ```
3. Run `sudo dpkg -l | grep apt` again to check version has changed. Hopefully the entry in the output should have changed to : **apt 1.0.10.2ubuntu2**.
4. Run a `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` following which you can proceed to update to ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: followed the advice listed. the command package manager did come up with ver. 1.0.10.2 ubuntu1. but the two commands to change to ubuntu2 did not yield a change(still ubuntu1). as this a security change, could it be caused by a security problem?

Comment: I am by no means an expert in this, but I think an another alternative would be to use [this deb](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/wily/amd64/apt/1.0.10.2ubuntu2)  to perhaps solve the problem.

Comment: i am uncomfortable downloading and installing ubuntu2 files until i can establish why the files are not available through the command line(terminal). i have limited experience extracting and installing from a download.

Answer (score 1):

The former posted solutions didn't work for me.

What worked was, as found in the comments on [launchpad](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+question/660149):

```
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/254524267/apt_1.0.10.2ubuntu2_amd64.deb   
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/254524264/apt-transport-https_1.0.10.2ubuntu2_amd64.deb
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/254524266/apt-utils_1.0.10.2ubuntu2_amd64.deb    
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/254524269/libapt-inst1.7_1.0.10.2ubuntu2_amd64.deb    
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/254524270/libapt-pkg4.16_1.0.10.2ubuntu2_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg --install apt_1.0.10.2ubuntu2_amd64.deb apt-transport-https_1.0.10.2ubuntu2_amd64.deb apt-utils_1.0.10.2ubuntu2_amd64.deb libapt-inst1.7_1.0.10.2ubuntu2_amd64.deb libapt-pkg4.16_1.0.10.2ubuntu2_amd64.deb

sudo do-release-upgrade
```